# how to release file that is in use by another program

Tags: c#, file, filelock

How to release file that is in use by another program in c#?

```
if(!IsFileLocked(fileName))
{
    // write in file
}
else
{    
   // first   ReleaseFile(fileName);    
   // two     write in file    
}
```

Comment: You can only release the file lock if you (your process/thread) own the file handle.

Comment: Due to this article : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e2044c5-ae5d-4552-a335-01cc567dfc58/how-to-unlock-a-file-used-by-other-process?forum=csharpgeneral ,  You may first to kill the process who use the file first.

Comment: @Dan-o: not true, else applications like [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) wouldn't be possible :-)

Comment: You shouldn't try to control other programs..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release a handle through C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225945/how-to-release-a-handle-through-c)

Comment: @DanPuzey: unlocker does some bad things.  It is generally not ok to close a handle that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: @Dan-o: agreed, but it's not impossible, and it seems that's what the OP is asking to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control other processes locking of files in C# natively. Your only option is to use Process.Kill to kill the processes locking the file, assuming you know which processes those are.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate question [How to release a handle through C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225945/how-to-release-a-handle-through-c)

use PInvoke if you have an handler that you want to close

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

Comment: If it's a duplicate question and you know it, you should not simply copy the answer 1:1 but just flag/vote to close the question as duplicate.